# Как эффективно объединить несколько pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Готовлю данные для модели, в частности заполняю пропуски для вещественных признаков и преобразую категориальные. Исходные данные имеют размерность `(40000, 230)`, из них первые 190 признаков вещественные, остальные — категориальные.

1. Подготовим вещественные данные для анализа. Заполним пропуски средним

   ```
   X_data = pd.DataFrame()
   for column in data.columns[:num_of_numerical_vars]:
       m1 = data[column].mean()
       if np.isnan(m1):
           m1 = data[column].notnull().mean()
       X_data[column] = data[column].fillna(m1)
   ```
2. Подготовим категориальные признаки. Воспользуемся `LabelEncoder` в 
   связке с `OneHotEncoder`

   ```
   label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
   data_categorical_num = data_categorical.apply(lambda col: label_encoder.fit_transform(col))
   hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
   encoded_categorical = hot_encoder.fit_transform(data_categorical_num)
   ```

Выводим размерность `encoded_categorical`

```
print encoded_categorical.shape
```

Вывод:

> (40000, 143513)

То есть данных довольно много. Подскажите, как в этом случае объединить получившиеся вещественные и категориальные признаки эффективно? Если написать что–то вроде:

```
pd_cats = pd.DataFrame(data=encoded_categorical)
X_data = pd.concat([X_data, pd_cats])
```

То на моем ПК не хватает памяти для данной операции. Как мне кажется, данные можно объединить как–то без копирования данных.

Данные могут быть загружены [отсюда](https://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data) ("small" dataset)

Comment: Можете выложить исходный дата сет?

Comment: @MaxU Добавил ссылку (данные те же, что и в предыдущем моем вопросе).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае стоит использовать [разреженные матрицы / фреймы](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

WORK_DIR = Path(r'D:\data\927487')

train = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train.data', sep='\t')    
labels = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train_appetency.labels', 
                     header=None, squeeze=True, dtype='int8')

categorical_cols = train.columns[train.dtypes.eq('object')]

train_cat = train[categorical_cols].copy()
train = pd.SparseDataFrame(train.drop(categorical_cols, axis=1))

train = train.join(
            pd.SparseDataFrame(
                mlb.fit_transform(
                    train_cat.T.apply(lambda c: c.dropna()
                                                 .str.cat(sep=' ')
                                                 .split())),
                default_fill_value=0))
```

Результат:

```
In [242]: type(train)
Out[242]: pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame

In [243]: train.memory_usage().sum()
Out[243]: 27806864     # NOTE: sparse DF takes only 27 MiB in RAM

In [244]: train.shape
Out[244]: (50000, 71696)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Подскажите, есть ли требования, когда необходимо переходить к разряженным таблицам? Как повлияет то, что у нас разреженная таблица на работу алгоритмов (той же регрессии)?

Comment: Если при работе с данными у вас не возникает `MemoryError` то вам возможно и не надо использовать разреженные матрицы. Для данных полученных после `One Hot Encoding` - разреженные таблицы занимают на порядки меньше памяти. Большинство известных мне алгоритмов регрессии в `SciKit-Learn` умеют напрямую работать с `Pandas.SparseDataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Несколько слов об обработке столбцов с преимущественно отсутствующими данными...

Если внимательно посмотреть на исходные данные, то можно заметить, что львиная доля (`154`) столбцов состоит из `NaN` на 90+%:

```
train = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train.data', sep='\t')    
labels = pd.read_csv(WORK_DIR / 'orange_small_train_appetency.labels', 
                     header=None, squeeze=True, dtype='int8')
```

оценка количества столбцов состоящих преимущественно из `NaN`:

```
In [52]: (train.isna().sum() / len(train) > 0.9).sum()
Out[52]: 154
```

мне кажется стоит попробовать построить регрессионную модель в которой данные столбцы не будут учавствовать вовсе и сравнить с той моделью, где такие данные заполнены средним значением (с высокой долей вероятности эти столбцы/признаки не сильно повлияют на результаты предсказываний):

```
In [54]: train = train.loc[:, train.isna().sum() / len(train) <= 0.9]

In [55]: train.shape
Out[55]: (50000, 76)
```

---

```
categorical_cols = train.columns[train.dtypes.eq('object')]

train_cat = train[categorical_cols].copy()
# drop categorical cols from the train DF
train = train.drop(categorical_cols, axis=1)
```

---

Чтобы заполнить `NaN` в оставшихся вещественных столбцах можно воспользоваться [sklearn.imputer.SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html). Кроме того стоит нормализовать данные, чтобы все признаки имели одинаковую шкалу величин - для этого существует [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

impute = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
scale = StandardScaler()

train = pd.SparseDataFrame(
          scale.fit_transform(impute.fit_transform(train)), 
          columns=train.columns, 
          index=train.index, 
          default_fill_value=0)

train = train.join(
            pd.SparseDataFrame(
                mlb.fit_transform(
                    train_cat.T.apply(lambda c: c.dropna()
                                                 .str.cat(sep=' ')
                                                 .split())),
                default_fill_value=0))
```

---

```
In [82]: train.memory_usage().sum()
Out[82]: 21455996

In [83]: train.shape
Out[83]: (50000, 71542)

In [84]: train.info()
<class 'pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 50000 entries, 0 to 49999
Columns: 71542 entries, Var6 to 71499
dtypes: float64(42), int32(71500)
memory usage: 20.5 MB
```

PS также стоит попробовать воспользоваться [методом главных компонент (`sklearn.decomposition.PCA`)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) для уменьшения размерности (уменьшить число признаков) выборки и сравнить результаты регрессии. PCA позволяет значительно уменьшить число признаков, выбрав самые значимые.

---

Как работает `MultilabelBinarizer`:

```
In [104]: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

In [105]: df = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:   'Col1': [10, 20, 30],
     ...:   'Col2': [['Apple','Orange','Banana'], ['Apple','Grape'], ['Banana']]
     ...: })

In [106]: df
Out[106]:
   Col1                     Col2
0    10  [Apple, Orange, Banana]
1    20           [Apple, Grape]
2    30                 [Banana]

In [107]: df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Col2']), index=df.index, columns=mlb.classes_))
Out[107]:
   Col1                     Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    10  [Apple, Orange, Banana]      1       1      0       1
1    20           [Apple, Grape]      1       0      1       0
2    30                 [Banana]      0       1      0       0
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Переписал код на предложенный вами. Действительно, работает много быстрее. Подскажите, пожалуйста: (1) Чем `SimpleImputer` лучше / отличается от исходного способа заполнения пустых значений? (2) Не могли бы вы коротко описать как работает `MultiLabelBinarizer`? (3) Вы предлагаете использовать PCA для всех признаков или для получившихся категориальных?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, мне кажется данный SO вопрос и ответы и так уже достаточно перегружены... Может стоит открыть новый вопрос? ;)

Comment: Да, конечно! Готово, задал еще два вопроса =)