# В чем преимущества sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer перед подсчетом среднего вручную?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Обрабатываю пропуски вещественных признаков, заполняя их средним:

```
X_data = pd.DataFrame()
for column in data.columns[:num_of_numerical_vars]:
    m1 = data[column].mean()
    if np.isnan(m1):
        m1 = data[column].notnull().mean()
    X_data[column] = data[column].fillna(m1)
```

В [соседнем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928342/6) мне рекомендовали использовать `SimpleImputer`.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

impute = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
impute.fit_transform(X_data)
```

Подскажите, в чем преимущества второго подхода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное преимущество в том, что используя `Simpleimputer` можно за один вызов заполнить пропущенные значения во всех числовых столбцах. Кроме этого можно выбрать стратегию заполнения отличную от заполнения средним арифметическим значением - можно, например, заполнять отсутствующие значения медианным значением, наиболее часто встречающимся значением или константным значением.

Еще одним преимуществом данного подхода является возможность комбинировать различные методы обработки в `SciKit-Learn` в `Pipeline` - [пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/792932/211923)