# Как работает sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Решал задачу подготовки категориальных данных. Использовал связку `LabelEncoder` с `OneHotEncoder`. Например:

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data_categorical_num = data_categorical.apply(lambda col: label_encoder.fit_transform(col))
hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
encoded_categorical = hot_encoder.fit_transform(data_categorical_num)
```

Мне [порекомендовали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/928298/6) использовать `MultiLabelBinarizer`, с которым я ранее не встречался. Подскажите, как работает `MultiLabelBinarizer`?

- В чем его преимущества и недостатки?
- Когда его следует и не следует применять?

Покажите, пожалуйста, несколько примеров его использования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) удобнее всего использовать в том случае если вы хотите получить `"One-Hot-Encoded"` данные из данных представленных в виде списка или кортежа.

Пример:

Пусть у нас есть следующий набор данных:

```
   Col1                     Col2
0    10  [Apple, Orange, Banana]
1    20           [Apple, Grape]
2    30                 [Banana]
```

нам необходимо сделать `One Hot Encoding` столбца `Col2` и получить:

```
   Col1  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    10      1       1      0       1
1    20      1       0      1       0
2    30      0       1      0       0
```

проще всего будет воспользоваться [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
In [8]: from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

In [9]: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

In [10]: df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('Col2')), index=df.index, columns=mlb.classes_))

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   Col1  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    10      1       1      0       1
1    20      1       0      1       0
2    30      0       1      0       0
```

---

При обработке текстов удобнее будет использовать [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), который умеет преобразовывать текст к нижнему регистру и работать с биграммами и N-граммами вместо обычных слов. Кроме этого можно гибко задать регулярное выражение для парсинга слова из текста.

Пример:

```
In [39]: df['Col2'] =  df['Col2'].apply(' '.join)

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   Col1                 Col2
0    10  Apple Orange Banana
1    20          Apple Grape
2    30               Banana

In [41]: df = df.join(pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(df.pop('Col2')), index=df.index, columns=cv.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value=0))

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
   Col1  apple  banana  grape  orange
0    10      1       1      0       1
1    20      1       0      1       0
2    30      0       1      0       0
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `CountVectorizer` привел все слова (`tokens`) к нижнему регистру.

---

`CountVectorizer` по умолчанию возвращает `Sparse Matrix`. При использовании  `MultiLabelBinarizer` надо явно указать параметр `MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)`, чтобы получить разреженную матрицу.

---

Если у нас во входных данных несколько категориальных (текстовых) столбцов, то проще всего преобразовать их в один столбец со списком слов или в один текстовый столбец, где слова разделены пробелами и преобразовать полученный единственный столбец к `One-Hot-Encoded` матрице за один вызов воспользовавшись соответственно `MultiLabelBinarizer` (список слов) или `CountVectorizer` (текст/предложения). При использовании `LabelEncoder` и `OneHotEncoder` придется обрабатывать все категориальные (текстовые) столбцы в цикле.